# Android MediaStore get distinct folders of music files

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Looking for the way to get only folder paths of music files from Android MediaStore for inputted directory path.  So actually question is about how to make proper query to the MediaStore.

Here is an example.
My current code:

```
String dirPath="/mnt/sdcard/Music/";
    String selection =MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA +" like ?";
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA};    
    String[] selectionArgs={dirPath+"%"};
    Cursor cursor = this.managedQuery(
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        projection,
        selection,
        selectionArgs,
        null);
    List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(cursor.moveToNext())
        songs.add(cursor.getString(0));
```

As a result we’ll have in the `songs` List smth like:

```
/mnt/sdcard/Music/song1.mp3
/mnt/sdcard/Music/song2.mp3
/mnt/sdcard/Music/FolderWithSongs/song3.mp3
/mnt/sdcard/Music/AnotherFolderWithSongs/song4.mp3
/mnt/sdcard/Music/AndOneMoreFolder/song5.mp3
/mnt/sdcard/Music/AndOneMoreFolder/song6.mp3
/mnt/sdcard/Music/AndOneMoreFolder/song7.mp3
/mnt/sdcard/Music/AndOneMoreFolder/SomeFolder/song8.mp3
/mnt/sdcard/Music/AndOneMoreFolder/SomeFolder/song9.mp3
```

What I’m actually looking for - to get such DISTINCT list of one-level nested paths from `dirPath` like this:

```
/mnt/sdcard/Music/FolderWithSongs/ 
/mnt/sdcard/Music/AnotherFolderWithSongs/ 
/mnt/sdcard/Music/AndOneMoreFolder/
```

If here will be current folder files - `/mnt/sdcard/Music/song1.mp3` and
`/mnt/sdcard/Music/song2.mp3` – it’s acceptable too.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**
I've found two possible solutions:
[Android list music by folders and play them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894576/android-list-music-by-folders-and-play-them) 
and [Construct a tree structure from list of string paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005551/construct-a-tree-structure-from-list-of-string-paths)
, but I think better way to solve this problem is possible.

Answer (score 9):

You  will have to use both technique .
MediaStore and file explorer .

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private File file;
private List<String> myList;
private ListView listView;
private TextView pathTextView;
private String mediapath = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());

private final static String[] acceptedExtensions= {"mp3", "mp2",    "wav", "flac", "ogg", "au" , "snd", "mid", "midi", "kar"
    , "mga", "aif", "aiff", "aifc", "m3u", "oga", "spx"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.pathlist);
    pathTextView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.path);

    myList = new ArrayList<String>();   

    String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    Log.e("Root",root_sd);

    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    File list[] = null ;
    /* if ( Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) || Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state) ) {  // we can read the External Storage...
        list=getAllFilesOfDir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
    }*/

    pathTextView.setText(root_sd);

    file = new File( root_sd ) ;       
    list = file.listFiles(new AudioFilter());
    Log.e("Size of list ","" +list.length);
    //LoadDirectory(root_sd);

    for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
    {

        String name=list[i].getName();
    int count =     getAudioFileCount(list[i].getAbsolutePath());
   Log.e("Count : "+count, list[i].getAbsolutePath());
   if(count!=0)
   myList.add(name);
        /*int count=getAllFilesOfDir(list[i]);
        Log.e("Songs count ",""+count);

        */  

    }


    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList ));

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            File temp_file = new File( file, myList.get( position ) );  

            if( !temp_file.isFile())        
            {
                //LoadDirectory(myList.get( position ));

                file = new File( file, myList.get( position ));
                File list[] = file.listFiles(new AudioFilter());

                myList.clear();

                for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
                {
                    String name=list[i].getName();

                    int count =     getAudioFileCount(list[i].getAbsolutePath());
                       Log.e("Count : "+count, list[i].getAbsolutePath());
                       if(count!=0)
                      myList.add(name);
                    /*int count=getAllFilesOfDir(list[i]);
                    Log.e("Songs count ",""+count);
                    if(count!=0)
                        myList.add(name);*/
                }

                pathTextView.setText( file.toString());
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), file.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList ));

            }


        }
    });



}

private int getAudioFileCount(String dirPath) {

        String selection =MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA +" like ?";
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA};    
        String[] selectionArgs={dirPath+"%"};
        Cursor cursor = this.managedQuery(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null);
        return cursor.getCount();
  }


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    try {
        String parent = file.getParent().toString();
        file = new File( parent ) ;         
        File list[] = file.listFiles(new AudioFilter());

        myList.clear();

        for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
        {
            String name=list[i].getName();
            int count =     getAudioFileCount(list[i].getAbsolutePath());
               Log.e("Count : "+count, list[i].getAbsolutePath());
               if(count!=0)
              myList.add(name);
            /*int count=getAllFilesOfDir(list[i]);
            Log.e("Songs count ",""+count);
            if(count!=0)*/

        }
        pathTextView.setText(parent);
    //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), parent,          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList ));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        finish();
    }


}



// class to limit the choices shown when browsing to SD card to media files
public class AudioFilter implements FileFilter {

    // only want to see the following audio file types
    private String[] extension = {".aac", ".mp3", ".wav", ".ogg", ".midi", ".3gp", ".mp4", ".m4a", ".amr", ".flac"};

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname) {

        // if we are looking at a directory/file that's not hidden we want to see it so return TRUE
        if ((pathname.isDirectory() || pathname.isFile()) && !pathname.isHidden()){
            return true;
        }

        // loops through and determines the extension of all files in the directory
        // returns TRUE to only show the audio files defined in the String[] extension array
        for (String ext : extension) {
            if (pathname.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(ext)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }      
}



}
```

.xml file :

```
<LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:textSize="21sp"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    android:id="@+id/path"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:text="PATH : " />

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="#111111" />

<ListView android:id="@+id/pathlist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</ListView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Permissions in manifiest file :

```
 <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Sad demo. Returns logcat error on line : list = file.listFiles(new AudioFilter());

Comment: Exactly, what I was looking for. This answer should have more upvotes. Nicely done.

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution.

1. scan all audio files ex) `Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
               MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ...`
2. declare new array
3. loop
4. Folder name = `MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA - MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME`
5. Put the new into array variable
6. array is a distinct folder list

Comment: I've tweaked the code a little so it's easier to read; can you check and make sure I've not removed anything that adds meaning?

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList<String> Get_Folder_Paths() {

         String[] columns = {
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,

    };

        ArrayList<String> FoldersList = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayList<String> DATAList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> DISPLAY_NAMEList = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                columns(),
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " = 1", null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                DATAList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)));
                DISPLAY_NAMEList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < DATAList.size(); i++) {
            FoldersList.add(DATAList.get(i).replace(DISPLAY_NAMEList.get(i), ""));

        }

        HashSet hs = new HashSet();

        hs.addAll(FoldersList); // demoArrayList= name of arrayList from which u want to remove duplicates

        FoldersList.clear();
        FoldersList.addAll(hs);

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return FoldersList;

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This may works:
- use walkDir method to search all music files in your storage location, then you could get the path of each file from getPath() method
- use subsString() method with all path files to get the level 1 folder name
- store all folder name in an ArrayList the use Hashset to remove duplicated folder name (with condition)